# Complex SQL query with where and where not in

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables (candidates, candidate_notes and candidate_events)

```
CANDIDATES  | CANDIDATE_NOTES       | CANDIDATE_EVENTS
id          | id                    | id
name        | candidate_event_id    | type
surname     | candidate_id
city        | note
...
```

One candidate can have many notes.

One note has one kind of event.

I would like to obtain all the candidates that have notes of kind of event 1 but only that.

For example, if the candidate 1 have 5 notes, one of type 1, other 3 of type 3 and another one of type 6, I don't want to see it in the results.

Can someone help me with this query?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `group by` and `having`:

```
select cn.candidate_id
from candidate_notes cn join
     candidate_events e
     on cn.candidate_event_id = e.candidate_event_id
group by cn.candidate_id
having min(type) = 1 and min(type) = max(type);
```